# Change highlight color for deadkey previews (like accents: `´^¨) in terminal app

Tags: macos, terminal, internationalization

I've been tweaking the theme / color preferences in the Terminal.app a bit, after a while I found that when pressing a diacritical mark/accent/dead key there's a **highlighted yellow rectangle** showing a preview of the accent you're inputting. Here's an screenshot:

[image]

It turns out is not editable from the terminal preferences. In fact it seems like a system wide setting.

But it IS incredibly annoying to guess what it is displaying with a dark background + lighter text color in the terminal app:

[image]

Is there anyway to change that yellow color to correctly read those symbols no matter what text/background color is?

Answer (score 0):

Check System Preferences > General > Highlight color to see if this yellow color has been selected. Perhaps another color would work better for your setup.

Comment: no, in fact that color was set to the default (blue).